# как по маске GetLogicalDrives(); определить какой из дисков является DVD(cd) Приводом?

Tags: c++

```
DWORD a = GetLogicalDrives(); // маска битовая
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdrivetypea

Comment: спасибо. помогло)))

Comment: string path = "e:";
int driveType = GetDriveTypeA(path.c_str()); cout << "e = " << driveType << endl; (
DRIVE_CDROM
5)